# VB.net listBox removing items

Tags: c#, vb.net, listbox

when i run this code it gives me an error which says value cannot be null

```
If (A >= 1) Then
    Item1 = fish
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Item1)
Else
    If (A = 0) Then
        If ListBox1.Items.Contains(Item1) = True Then
            While ListBox1.Items.Contains(Item1) = True
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(Item1)
            End While
        End If
    End If
End If
```

the error comes at this line

```
If ListBox1.Items.Contains(Item1) = True Then
```

also all integers are dim-ed already

what i am trying to do is if the listbox contain item 1 should be deleted

the code work if i gave A value of 1 then changed it to 0

but if i gave the A  value of 0 from the beginning the code will crash

please help

thank you

Comment: because at that time Item1 is `Nothing` so add a check for `Nothing`.

Comment: so what would you suggest a fix @NikhilAgrawal

Comment: Can you help me with the code please @NikhilAgrawal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
If ListBox1.Items.Contains(Item1) = True Then
```

to

```
If Item1 IsNot Nothing AndAlso ListBox1.Items.Contains(Item1) Then
```